# Why does this proxy handler cause infinite recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion, es6-proxy

I built a hook for the `toString` method using ES6 Proxy. While debugging some issues I noticed the `console.log` of handler getting called for no reason.

```js
class Hook {
    constructor(object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    toStringProperty() {
        const handler = {
            apply: (target, thisArg, args) => {

                console.log(target, thisArg, args);

                if (thisArg === Function.prototype.toString) {
                    return 'function toString() { [native code] }'
                }

                if (thisArg === this.object) {
                    return "Hooked String"
                }

                return target.apply(thisArg, args)
            }
        }

        Function.prototype.toString = new Proxy(Function.prototype.toString, handler)
    }
}

let hook = new Hook(HTMLAudioElement);
hook.toStringProperty()
HTMLAudioElement.toString();
```

I spent a lot of time trying to find what causes this recursion but I'm afraid that I can't find anything.

Note: this behavior also happens after typing `HTMLAudioElement` or `ooo` in console and of course you have to do this after running the above code. My browser is Chrome. I tested with Devtools Console.

[image]

Comment: The snippet in your question does not appear to have an infinite loop. Run it, and execution finishes normally.

Comment: @CertainPerformance If you wait 2-5 min, it will kick in.

Comment: @CertainPerformance See my screenshot.

Comment: "*I built a hook for the `toString` method using ES6 Proxy.*" - don't do that. If you have to overwrite `Function.prototype.toString` (and you really shouldn't), overwrite it with a normal function not with an unnecessary proxy!

Comment: Been running the snippet for 15 minutes and I haven't seen anything logged. I don't think the function will just randomly call its own `toString`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Did you wait for sometime or maybe it trigger when you paste `HTMLAudioElement` like I did in screenshot?

Comment: I waited for 15 minutes with the snippet running and didn't see anything

Comment: @Bergi Describe the reasons why don't..

Comment: @CertainPerformance Did you paste `HTMLAudioElement` on console?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I noted that it trigger that way, even if you type `ooo` it trigger.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Looks like it also trigger if you invoke `HTMLAudioElement .toString()` so you don't have to wait.. Instant result..

Comment: @jeffbRTC Don't use proxies mainly because of unnecessary complexity. YAGNI!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the handler, you call `console.log(target, thisArg, args);` where `target` and `thisArg` are functions. The devtools console appears to use `.toString()` to get the name of the function to display it.

Comment: Also, the target causing that as-well.